# How to Get each 5 items from the list

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

I have a list with 8 Items.

I need to Get each 5 items from the list

Code that i tried :

```
lstRules.ToList()
    .GetRange(((currentPage - 1) * pageSize + 1) - 1, (currentPage * pageSize));
```

IF `CurrentPage = 1 and  Pagesize = 5` then the aove code works correctly because here i pass the range of (0,5)...

and If `CurrentPage = 2 and PageSize = 5`
then it throws the error like below :

**"Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection"**

I know this error occur because i have only `3` items in the list and i pass the range of `(5,5)`... so i got this error..

My question here is how to solve this issue?

Is there any other way to get the data from the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do soemthing like this:

if you have current `pageNumber` and know how much records per page you define: `recordsPerPage`, the general purpose query would look like this

```
var currentPageData = lstRules.ToList().
                          Skip(pageNumber * recordsPerPage).Take(recordsPerPage);
```

Comment: hi let take this i have 8 items in the list... pagenumber is 1 and records per page is 5 then your code look like this right.... `lstRules.ToList().Skip(5).Take(5)`...

Comment: +1 - @Pandian Just remember your first page should be considered pageNumber 0 (and not 1)

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ instead:

```
var data = lstRules.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Alternatively, you could use a library that already does the work for you, such as [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use something like [the `Batch` method from `MoreLinq`](http://nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.Batch/).

This lets you partition the items in a sequence into batches of a specified size.

If you want a simple approach which doesn't need to be threadsafe (i.e. you don't need to use it with `Parallel.ForEach()` for example) then you can use the following extension method.

It has the advantage that you can produce all the batches without calling Skip multiple times:

```
public sealed class Batch<T>
{
    public readonly int Index;
    public readonly IEnumerable<T> Items;

    public Batch(int index, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Index = index;
        Items = items;
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExt
{
    // Note: Not threadsafe, so not suitable for use with Parallel.Foreach() or IEnumerable.AsParallel()

    public static IEnumerable<Batch<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int batchSize)
    {
        var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
        int index = 0;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return new Batch<T>(index++, nextBatch(enumerator, batchSize));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> nextBatch<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int blockSize)
    {
        do { yield return enumerator.Current; }
        while (--blockSize > 0 && enumerator.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

And you use it like:

```
    var items = Enumerable.Range(100, 510); // Pretend we have 50 items.
    int itemsPerPage = 20;

    foreach (var page in items.Partition(itemsPerPage))
    {
        Console.Write("Page " + page.Index + " items: ");

        foreach (var i in page.Items)
            Console.Write(i + " ");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

But if you need threadsafe partitioning, use the MoreLinq Batch method I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

```
lstRules.Take(5);
```